# Setting isInstanceOf class as variable

Tags: scala

Given MyClass1 and MyClass2 that extend MyAbstractClass, I need to implement a logic where the type used in `isInstanceOf` is variable (see `myFunction` below). Is this feasible?

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  val a: Int
  val b: Int
}

class MyClass1 extends MyAbstractClass {
  val c: String
}

class MyClass2 extends MyAbstractClass {
  val d: Int
}



object HelloScala extends App {


    def myFunction(indicator: Int) = {

      val MyClass = if (indicator  == 1) MyClass1 else MyClass2

      if (someObject.isInstanceOf[MyClass])
          // do something
      else
          // do something else

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for using a variable in the value between the brackets of isInstanceOf, for example the variable MyClass in my question is a variable used by isInstanceOf. The code in my question does not compile and I'm looking to fix it.

You can't do this literally, but you can achieve using an actual [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) value which Scala gives you with `classOf` and its `isInstance` method:

```
val myClass = if (indicator == 1) classOf[MyClass1] else classOf[MyClass2]
if (myClass.isInstance(someObject)) ...
```

Comment: what I'm looking for is actually `someObject.isInstanceOf[myClass]`, following your example, but apparently is not doable.

Comment: No, it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching instead of `isInstanceOf`

```
def myFunction(indicator: Int) = {

  someObject match {
    case x: MyClass1 if indicator == 1 => doSomething()
    case x: MyClass2 if indicator != 1 => doSomething()
    case _ => doSomethingElse()
  }


}
```

#### Simpler version

```
 (someObject, indicator) match {
    case (_: MyClass1, 1) | (_: MyClass2, y) if y != 1  => doSomething()
    case _ => doSomethingElse()
  }
```

#### Using isInstanceOf

```
if (someObject.isInstanceOf[MyClass1] && indicator == 1)
      // do something
else if (someObject.isInstanceOf[MyClass2] && indicator != 1)
      // do something
else // do Something else
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use `isInstanceOf`, in the question I put a simplified version of the code. I need to use a variable in the value between brackets of `isInstanceOf`.

Comment: @ps0604 added `instanceOf` based code as well . Have a look

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for using a **variable** in the value between the brackets of `isInstanceOf`, for example the variable `MyClass` in my question is a variable used by `isInstanceOf`. The code in my question does not compile and I'm looking to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I think you are heading the wrong direction. Scala allows object oriented programming (together with FP, which is one of the main advantages over pure FP languages). So why not using typical inheritance here?

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {

  def logic();
}

class MyClass1 extends MyAbstractClass {
  val c: String

  def logic() {
    ...
  }
}

class MyClass2 extends MyAbstractClass {
  val d: Int

  def logic() {
    ...
  }
}

object HelloScala extends App {


    def myFunction(indicator: Int) = {

      val obj: MyClass = if (indicator  == 1) new MyClass1() else new MyClass2()

      obj.logic()


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't need the object:

```
    (indicator, someObjectIDontWantToUse) match {
       case (1, _: MyClass1) | (_, _: MyClass2) => doSomething()
       case _ => doSomethingElse()
    }
```

In case you need it:

```
    (indicator, someObjectIWantToUse) match {
       case (1, someObject: MyClass1) => doSomethingWith(someObject)
       case (_, someObject: MyClass2) => doSomethingWith(someObject)
       case _ => doSomethingElseWith(someObject)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for using an argument in `isInstanceOf`

Comment: This is wrong because it passes for (1, MyClass2Instance)